# Android aways on top activity

Tags: android, android-activity

How can I make an activity
that stay on the top of all other applications?

something such as this

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gooutnplay.antsinmypants&hl=en

Thanks.

Comment: How about using fragments to achive this.

Comment: maybe I did not clarify my needs clearly. The link in the post for the application "Ants in my Pants" it's displayed on the screen regardless of which application is running. I want to do something similar.

Comment: This is a good starting point: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)

Comment: Take a look at this question : [Creating a system overlay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-always-on-top-button-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a hack of the permission [`SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW), which allows the app to draw on top of any other app.